# Xcode 5 fails to simulate location on iOS 7 devices

Tags: core-location, xcode5, simulate, gpx

I can't seem to be able to simulate locations using Xcode 5 with iOS 7 devices or the iOS 7 simulator. However when running the same app on an iOS 6 device it works fine. Is there any workaround for this or has the GPX format required changed?

Comment: It looks like toggling breakpoints on/off makes the simulator simulate location but simulating location on an iOS 7 device still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best workaround I've found is to set the default location on the scheme under the options tab. The biggest downside is that you can't change the location after you set the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If the simulator is having problem while simulating locations, quit and launch the simulator again.

Comment: this worked for me on xcode 6 when i had a problem simulating location on iphone 5, 5s, 6 (it was working for 6plus)

Answer (score 0):

Threw me as well and drove me mad trying to find it.

It's still there but its now in the Debug Menu in Xcode 5.

works just like it used to do when it was in plain sight . sigh

Answer (score 0):

You can do this that way in menu.

> You can change the simulated location by choosing a location from the Debug > Simulate Location menu.

[Reference Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html)